# configure destination dir for install assets in symfony

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I am trying to work with assetic for my assets.

I made an dir: AppBundle/Resources/public
In there: (AppBundle/Resources/public/images) i save my images

if i do: php bin/console assets:install all of the images in that dir will be copied to the web/bundles/app/images map

I can use those images in twig:

But i like those images to be stored in the main web/images in stead of web/bundles/app/images

How do in make assets:install install the images in the web/images folder?

Second question, is it possible to make assets:install read from AppBundle/Resources/public/fotos in stead of AppBundle/Resources/public/images?
if so how do i configure that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can configure assetic. Here are default values:

```
assetic:
    read_from:            '%assetic.read_from%'
    write_to:             '%kernel.root_dir%/../web'
```

More info http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Comment: I have in my app/config/config.yml file:

Comment: debug:          '%kernel.debug%'

Comment: use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'

Comment: write_to:             '%kernel.root_dir%/../web'